# (a/b) mod n for large numbers?

Tags: c, modulo

I need to calculate the sum of first n tetranacci numbers but the formula which I am using

```
sn = (f(n+2)+2*f(n)+f(n-1)-1)/3
```

has a division involved.
I am doing `f(n) modulo 10^9 + 7` to calculate nth tetranacci term. For some cases, it gives the correct answer but not for all.

Can someone please help me get the correct logic on how to calculate it?

Comment: Wild guess: use a larger data type.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a specific example of a value of f(n) that doesn't give the correct answer.

Comment: eulers theorm hmm is this from project euler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For modular arithmetics, replace the division by a multiplication with the modular inverse.

If `k*d ≡ 1 (mod m)` and `n` is a multiple of `d`, then

```
n/d ≡ ((n % m)*k % m) (mod m)
```

You can see that by

```
k = (f*m + 1)/d
n*k = (n*(f*m + 1))/d = ((n*f)*m + n)/d = (n/d)*(f*m) + (n/d)
```

Now, `n/d` is by assumption an integer, hence `(n/d)*(f*m)` is a multiple of `m`, so

```
n*k ≡ n/d (mod m)
```

and since

```
n*k ≡ (n % m)*k (mod m)
```

the proposition follows.

In this case, `d = 3` and `m = 10^9 + 7`, so `k = (10^9 + 8)/3 = 333333336`.

If `n` is *not* a multiple of `d`, that doesn't work, however.

Comment: Neat, but I don't think this will solve the OP's issue (which is likely to be an overflow problem).

Answer (score 0):

If you have your number in a digit array, you can calculate the mod for this big number using this:

```
long mod_ans = 0;

for(i = 0; i < digits_array_length; i++)

{

    int digit = digits_array[i];
    mod_ans = (mod_ans * 16 + digit) % num;
}
```